# How can i add custom shortcodes in Redactor

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, redactor, redactor.js

Is there any way to add custom short codes in "imperavi Redactor" ?
for example user has a list of short codes in a dropdown and user select from there and it will get added in the text area.